# AES shared Key with RSA public Key

Tags: encryption, aes, rsa

I found a very good public private key encryption tutorial [here](http://www.macs.hw.ac.uk/~ml355/lore/pkencryption.htm). This tutorial uses an RSA public key algorithm and the AES shared key algorithm.

I am thinking of designing a client,server architecture where the client keeps the private key, the server keeps the public key. The username + salt is encrypted by the private key and sent to the server along with the AES shared key. The server uses the AES Shared key + Public key to decrypt the information. Is this method secure ? Is there any better way to use Public-Private-Key authentication ?

Comment: Why not use TLS? For secure communication it's almost always a better choice than custom crypto.

Comment: Can you provide a link ? Whats the difference between the two ?

Comment: TLS is a higher level protocol designed for secure communication. You're attempting to design your own protocol instead of using an existing protocol. Designing a good protocol is tricky and requires experience with cryptography. Consider forward secrecy, server authentication, active attacks on your encryption such as padding oracles, replay attacks, which padding you use for RSA, which mode of operation you use for AES, how you generate the IVs and many more details. If you even get a single one of these wrong, your security breaks down.

Comment: If you need only to authenticate securely, then SRP is probably one of the most advanced choices you have. Check [SRP home](http://srp.stanford.edu/) and [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Remote_Password_protocol).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about cryptography. First describe the protocol using formal language, check for dupes and post on security.stackexchange.com . Or use a premade format such as CMS or OpenPGP. Or, if you want transport security, use SSL (TLS).

Answer (score 1):

I think you are supposed to encrypt information with public key, and then decrypt it with private key of server. Public key from definition is the one exposed to everyone, so in your case everyone can decrypt the message sent from client, including aes key.

Comment: So if i swap the keys, in theory my architecture is secure [enough]?